# Network Sharing Apps within the App

Tags: ios

I am enable to get the answer from last couple of Weeks that

Actually I have 1 tableview contains some text, and I have Sharing bar button  if  iClicked that Sharing Barbutton At Index    i need to Share that text to Email,FB,WhatsuP,and other that are Installed and supported to send text.

finally my requirement is when I clicked the bar button, i need to open the view that contains the list of Installed Apps in our device(Email,FB,WhatsUp,etc)That are supported to send text.
 and When I clicked The Item in the List, text should send to That App.

I have no idea and I am searching for it from few couple of weeks

Please Help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UIActivityViewController`

```
NSString *shareText = @"some text to share";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someurl.com"];
NSArray *itmes = @[shareText, items];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
```

If you wish you can also exlude some of the items in the activityVC like

```
activityVC.excludeActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypePostToTensentWeibo];
 // and as many more you like
```

Comment: Thankyou Very much, Actually I now About this Class But I don't no is it gets only the Apps that are installed with in the device

Comment: You can include or exclude apps from share options. Search the net for tutorails on `UIActivityViewController`

Comment: Can I And Song file instead of url to SocialNetworks(WhatsUp etc) through UIActivityViewController....?,   Help me Anyone